# Transforming nested array of objects using jq

Tags: json, jq

How can I transform the JSON input

```
{
"Subnets": [
    {
        "VpcId": "vpc-xxx",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "staging_subnet_private_a",
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ],
        "SubnetId": "subnet-xxx"
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

to

```
[
 {
  "SubnetId": "subnet-xxx",
  "Name": "staging_subnet_private_a"
 },
 ...
]
```

using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

I have a working solution using `jq '[.Subnets[] | {SubnetId, Name: .Tags[0] | .Value }]'`, but this relies on the order of Tags (not good).

Could I use `from_entires` or reduce maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use `from_entries`. In jq 1.5rc1 and above, it is defined as taking `Key`/`Value` key names as well as `key`/`value`.

Try something like:

`jq '.Subnets | map({SubnetId} + (.Tags | from_entries))'`

On previous versions, you could modify the "entries" before passing them to `from_entries`:

`jq '.Subnets | map({SubnetId} + (.Tags | map({value: .Value, key: .Key}) | from_entries))'`

Comment: Depending on the requirements, mapping all tags might include too much. So an additional `select` call would help limit what's used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which only uses jq primitives.

```
[
  .Subnets[]
| {SubnetId} + (.Tags[] | if .Key=="Name" then {Name:.Value} else empty end)
]
```